# Custom Post Type used for FAQs Accordion

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories, taxonomy

OK, so I asked this earlier and no one had any answer for me. I have a CPT for FAQs. FAQs are separated into 'categories.' I need the name of the 'category' then a every post within that 'category.'

Example:

### Category 1

#### Title of Post 1 within Category 1

Content of Post 1 within Category 1

#### Title of Post 2 within Category 1

Content of Post 2 within Category 1

### Category 2

#### Title of Post 1 within Category 2

Content of Post 1 within Category 2

#### Title of Post 2 within Category 2

Content of Post 2 within Category 2

The code that I now have is:

```
        <?// for a given post type, return all except 'uncategorized'
            $post_type = 'faq';
            $tax = 'category';
            $tax_terms = get_terms($tax, array('orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'ASC', 'exclude' => '1'));
            if ($tax_terms) {
                foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => $post_type,
                        "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'caller_get_posts' => 1
                        ); // END $args
                    $my_query = null;
                    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                    if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
                        echo '<div class="aro"><div class="wrap"><h2>' . $tax_term->name . '</h2></div><div class="details"><div class="wrap">';
                        
                        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

                                <div class="info">
                                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                </div>

        <?php
                        endwhile; } // END if have_posts loop
                        echo '</div></div></div>'; // Close 'details', 'wrap', & 'aro' DIVs
                wp_reset_query(); } // END foreach $tax_terms
            } // END if $tax_terms
        ?>
```

This code does list every 'category' individually, which I do want. However, every post within FAQs is listed under every 'category,' which is not what I want. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure. I found this code while looking for my answer and tailored to my application. I did notice the "$tax" part and thought it didn't took right. Could that part of my problem?

Comment: It looks like one of the query arguments is not working, because the logic looks correct. Try removing the quotations from $tax and checking that all variables have the expected values.

Comment: That didn't change anything. Also, the 'categories' that I was were referring to, I believe they are categories and not taxonomies. If that is correct. Not sure about those two and how they are different.

Comment: Categories is a taxonomy -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

Also, take a look at the codex for querying taxonomies with wp_query -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

It's best if you understand how things work.

Comment: Thanks. And I agree with understanding. I now get that Categories is the taxonomy. And any category I select or create in the post is the taxonomy term. Obviously, $tax_term->name is the name of my term. I'm just having trouble understanding to only list the posts of the term, instead of all.

Comment: I see the 'post_type' => $post_type is my problem. It's pulling all FAQs in. How can I limit this to the terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have double posted this question, and in your comment in the previous question you said that you don't know if you are using build-in categories or custom taxonomies.

Essentially, built-in categories and custom taxonomies are both [Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies), and the "categories" that you create in the back end are in actual fact just terms of the taxonomy 'category', so essentially, your query will be exactly the same for both build-in categories and custom taxonomies

If you need to know if you are dealing with categories or custom taxonomies within a post type, you can use [`get_object_taxonomies`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies) to retrieve these information. This function will also be used later to retrieve a list of categories or custom taxonomies to compile your custom query. Just change `$post_type` to the actual name of your post type, in your case faq

```
$taxonomy_names = get_object_taxonomies( '$post_type' );
   print_r( $taxonomy_names);
```

If you are using custom taxonomies, the following will be returned

```
Array ( [0] => TAXONOMY_NAME )
```

If you are using categories, the following will be returned

```
Array
(
    [0] => category
    [1] => post_tag
    [2] => post_format
)
```

Ok, done with the nitty gritty stuff. Lets get to the query. You are almost there. The correct way here is to use the taxonomy parameters within [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to construct your query.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'POST TYPE OF WHICH POSTS YOU WANT TO RETRIEVE',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'NAME OF YOUR TAXONOMY',
            'field' => 'WHICH FIELD TO USE TO RETRIEVE TERMS',
            'terms' => 'NAME OF YOUR TERM'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Another thing of note, `caller_get_posts` is longtime depreciated, and was replaced with `ignore_sticky_posts`

This is how your final query should look like. I just copied, corrected and tested your code as is, so if there are any other modifications that you need to make, feel free and adapt

```
<?php 
$post_type = 'faq';
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post_type );

foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'ASC', 'exclude' => '1'));

    if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $args = array(
                'post_type'           => $post_type,
                'orderby'             => 'title',
                'order'               => 'ASC',
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                'post_status'         => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page'      => - 1,
                'tax_query'           => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'    => $taxonomy,
                        'field'       => 'slug',
                        'terms'       => $term->slug
                    )
                )
            );
            $my_query = null;
            $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
            if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
                echo '<div class="aro"><div class="wrap"><h2>' . $term->name . '</h2></div><div class="details"><div class="wrap">';

                    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

                        <div class="info">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>

                    <?php
                    endwhile; 
            } // END if have_posts loop
                echo '</div></div></div>'; // Close 'details', 'wrap', & 'aro' DIVs
            wp_reset_query(); 
        } // END foreach $terms
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about the double post. I deleted the other. I greatly appreciate your explanations and the updated code.

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help. Enjoy :-)